# TypeLite fresh install doesn't work

Tags: typelite

I just installed TypeLite into my project via NuGet, but it doesn't work, and everything I've tried hasn't helped... This is the file that was created after installing:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="True" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)TypeLite.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)TypeLite.Net4.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)" #>

<#@ import namespace="TypeLite" #> 
<#@ import namespace="TypeLite.Net4" #> 
<#@output extension=".d.ts"#>

 <#@include file="Manager.ttinclude"#>
<# var manager = Manager.Create(Host, GenerationEnvironment); #>

<# var ts = TypeScript.Definitions()
        .WithReference("Enums.ts")
        .ForLoadedAssemblies();
#>

<#= ts.Generate(TsGeneratorOutput.Properties) #>

<# manager.StartNewFile("Enums.ts"); #>
<#= ts.Generate(TsGeneratorOutput.Enums) #>
<# manager.EndBlock(); #>
<# manager.Process(true); #>
```

This is the error I get:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       Running transformation: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at TypeLite.TsModelBuilder.Add(Assembly assembly)
   at TypeLite.Net4.TypeScriptFluentExtensions.ForLoadedAssemblies(TypeScriptFluent ts)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating097C215A707CB07DE5AACDA590F263DF8554A0CCA899B583BF1832F7C0C5D3E595312AE41D3DFD1BB9CA643458AA5D86FE3DBA281ED0000D4B4C1D87EA1DEFFB.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText() MyApp   S:\MyApp\Scripts\TypeLite.Net4.tt   1
```

If I choose "Debug T4 template" this is what I get:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       Running transformation: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
       at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   at TypeLite.Extensions.TypeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute[TType](Type type, Boolean inherit)
   at TypeLite.TsModelBuilder.<Add>b__4(Type t)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereArrayIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at TypeLite.TsModelBuilder.Add(Assembly assembly)
   at TypeLite.Net4.TypeScriptFluentExtensions.ForLoadedAssemblies(TypeScriptFluent ts)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating097C215A707CB07DE5AACDA590F263DF8554A0CCA899B583BF1832F7C0C5D3E595312AE41D3DFD1BB9CA643458AA5D86FE3DBA281ED0000D4B4C1D87EA1DEFFB.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText() in s:\MyApp\Scripts\TypeLite.Net4.tt:line 13

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : Breeze.WebApi2, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f6085f1a45e2ac59.
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/System.Web.Http.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/System.Web.Http/System.Web.Http.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/System.Web.Http.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/System.Web.Http/System.Web.Http.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///S:/MyApp/bin/System.Web.Http.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Build Number
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///S:/MyApp/bin/System.Web.Http/System.Web.Http.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///S:/MyApp/bin/System.Web.Http.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///S:/MyApp/bin/System.Web.Http/System.Web.Http.EXE.   MyApp   s:\MyApp\Scripts\TypeLite.Net4.tt   13
```

If I add this to the file:

<#@ assembly name="System.Web.Http.dll" #>

Then I get:

```
Error       Compiling transformation: Assembly 'WebUI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'    MyApp   S:\MyASpp\Scripts\TypeLite.Net4.tt  1
```

Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure out where that 5.2.2 reference is; everything in my projects is 5.2.3. If I take the file path to my 5.2.3 DLL and put that in (which is c:\packages... from nuget), it works.

I guess my question is why doesn't it find the DLL reference via the project, or is there a better way to do this? I won't want to have to hard-code paths in this file, ideally I wouldn't need to specify them at all, but I don't know how else to do it at this point.

Comment: We encountered a similar issue and it was not solvable.
We ended up creating a small console application and copied the code from the T4 template there.

Comment: Where were you getting that error? I get no output ANYWHERE, I just get a .d.ts file with "ErrorGeneratingOutput" in it. Totally useless. I guess now the next few days for me is writing my own TypeScript templating software. Marvellous.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error.  In my case, all the files that I wanted to be handled by typeLite were in the same assembly so I soved the problem by restricting to the one assembly using the following (in the .tt file):

```
<# var ts = TypeScript.Definitions()
    .For(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyWebProject.SomeClass)));
#>
```

Answer (score 0):

T4 templates doesn't know anything about packages installed in your project, so it is necessary to add reference to used assemblies manually.

Obviously T4 is trying to load a wrong version of the library. I would check whether your `bin` folder contains the correct version of the assembly and I would try to reference the library from there.

```
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)System.Web.Http.dll" #>
```